# Attempting to unhide additional column if any cell in range meets criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

My spreadsheet is laid out with repeating rows for the manual verification of data.  Column "I" contains a drop down via Data Validation with 3 options.  I am attempting to keep an additional column "K" hidden unless the (rare) case that option "N/A" is chosen from the drop down.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       If Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
          If Target.Value = "N/A" Then
            Act3
          Else
           Act4
      End If
      Else
        Act4
      End If
    End Sub

 Sub Act3()
     Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
 End Sub

 Sub Act4()
     Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 End Sub
```

My code may be a bit crude, but it at least unhides the column when correct criteria is chosen.  My problem is that if another cell is given a selection that does not require the additional column, it then hides the column again.  What am I missing?  Is there a function that allows something along the lines of:

'If Any in Range Then'

Comment: Are you referring to a text constant of `N/A` or the worksheet error `#N/A` ? What range of cells should change the visibility of the column? Anything in column I or a specific cell in column I?

Comment: You may want to try `If IsError(target) Then`  instead of what you have. Or try `If Target.Value = "#N/A" Then` ...

Comment: "N/A" is an actual choice within the Data Validation drop down box.  K4:K54 are the cells that are given the drop down.  Entire column I should become visible. @Jeeped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding my AnyNA function. It goes through your whole column to check for N/A and does not hide when any are found.

It seems you only want to consider hiding if it's not hidden and vice versa, so I optimized for you. Also removed redundant "= True" and changed sub names to "Hide" and "Unhide" for clarity.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden And Target.Value = "N/A" Then
        Unhide
    ElseIf Not Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden And Not AnyNA Then
        Hide
    End If
End Sub

Private Function AnyNA() As Boolean
    For Row = 1 To Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If Range("J" & Row).Value = "N/A" Then
            AnyNA = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    AnyNA = False
End Function

Sub Unhide()
    Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End Sub

Sub Hide()
    Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I can follow the logic here, but I am having trouble with the syntax.  I am new to VBA so this may be simple. I am getting syntax errors on 'Unhide()' 'Hide()' and 'Private Function AnyNA() As Boolean' @Sean Scott

Comment: N/m I corrected this by taking the () away from the call lines and correcting End Sub to End Function.

Now, it correctly unhides the column when "N/A" is chosen in column "I", but when I move on to the next row, regardless of what I choose, it hides column "K" again.

Comment: I thought it did.  It is now unhiding correctly, but doesn't rehide if the cell is adjusted away from "N/A".

Comment: I fixed my answer. I was using incorrect syntax in AnyNA as well. Since I didn't call Exit Function, it always returned False. I also forgot to switch the checked column to "J". Try now

Answer (score 0):

With the assistance of @Sean Scott, I have found the solution:

```
    Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      If Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden Then
         If Target.Value = "N/A" Then
            UnhideDocs
         End If
      ElseIf Not Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden And Not Target.Value = "N/A" Then
         HideDocs
      End If
  End Sub

 Function AnyNA() As Boolean
   For Row = 1 To Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Range("K" & Row).Value = "N/A" Then
        AnyNA = True
    End If
   Next
    AnyNA = False
 End Function


  Sub UnhideDocs()
     Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
  End Sub

  Sub HideDocs()
     Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  End Sub
```